# heating ham at 200 degrees versus 325 degrees

Tags: cooking-time

If I am heating a fully cooked ham that directs me to cook at 325 degrees F for 20 minutes per pound (ham is 3.38#) and I want to heat it through at a 200 degree F temp. How long should I put the ham in the oven for?

Comment: Why do you want to heat it at 200? That's really low, to the point that it seems likely to stay at an unsafe temperature for quite a while.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Do you mean that you want the final temp to be 200°F, or the oven temp would be 200°F?

Comment: @Jefromi Why unsafe? It's already fully cooked. Slow cookers and some slow roasting dishes can be prepared at even lower temperatures.

Comment: @Robert Safely cooked food can still become unsafe if held long enough in the danger zone. It presumably takes quite a while for 200F air to get a refrigerated or room temperature ham above 140F. I'm not saying it's *definitely* unsafe, just that it's headed in that direction, so it's worth asking what the goal is. (And sure, slow cookers do hold below boiling like that, but the idea is to get up to that temperature reasonably quickly.)

Answer (score 5):

Not knowing what kind of oven you have or what cut the ham is, bone in or bone out etc., I would recommend that you simply buy an inexpensive meat thermometer (less than $10 in most places) and check the ham's internal temperature every two hours or so.

Answer (score 0):

Glaze the Ham. Put in oven at 170f at 9pm. Turn heat up to 350f at 5 am. Let brown. Remove & have some for breakfast. At 6am nice & hot.

Answer (score 0):

Place ham on a rack in a shallow uncovered pan with the fat side (skin side) up so the ham will baste itself. 6) Roasting time is 30 minutes per pound of ham at 200 Degrees F. However it is recommended to use a meat thermometer and cook until the internal temperature reaches 155 Degrees.

Answer (score 0):

You can cook it at 200 and you'll be just fine. If you've ever eaten smoked Foods they are cooked at a low temperature between 200 and 250. The weight determines the length of time that it takes.

Comment: Hi Chris. Welcome to the site.  We appreciate your input and look forward to more.  However, your answer to this question does not directly provide an answer (How long will it take?).  If you can either edit it to address the specific question (that's our goal here), or delete it, that would be appreciated.